# Receiving data only if sent python socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, try-catch, recv

I am writing a messenger application in python and I have a problem. The problem is quite simple: I want the program to only receive data from the other computer if it was sent, otherwise, my program would wait for a data transfer infinitely. How would I write that piece of code? I imagine it'd be something like this:

```
    try:
        data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    except:
        data == None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `select` module.  A socket can be monitored for readability with a timeout, so other process can proceed.

Example server:

```
import socket
import select

with socket.socket() as server:
    server.bind(('',5000))
    server.listen(3)
    to_read = [server]  # add server to list of readable sockets.
    clients = {}
    while True:
        # check for a connection to the server or data ready from clients.
        # readers will be empty on timeout.
        readers,_,_ = select.select(to_read,[],[],0.5)
        for reader in readers:
            if reader is server:
                client,address = reader.accept()
                print('connected',address)
                clients[client] = address # store address of client in dict
                to_read.append(client) # add client to list of readable sockets
            else:
                # Simplified, really need a message protocol here.
                # For example, could receive a partial UTF-8 encoded sequence.
                data = reader.recv(1024)
                if not data: # No data indicates disconnect
                    print('disconnected',clients[reader])
                    to_read.remove(reader) # remove from monitoring
                    del clients[reader] # remove from dict as well
                else:
                    print(clients[reader],data.decode())
        print('.',flush=True,end='')
```

A simple client, assuming your IP address is 1.2.3.4.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('1.2.3.4',5000))
s.sendall('hello'.encode())
s.close()
```

Comment: Will this allow devices on other networks to connect to the server or only devices within the server's network? If second, what would the client need for the server's address?

Comment: @Chris That depends on your network.  For example, If you are behind a home router you would need to open a port on the firewall for Internet users to access it.  `server.bind(('',5000))` will let anybody connect assuming there is a network route.

Comment: Then what would, eg. my friend, need to connect to at port 5000?

Comment: @Chris I added a short example.  If your server is behind a home router, your friend will need the public internet address and you must configure your router to forward port 5000 to your local server.  You can google "what is my IP address" or use a service like https://whatismyipaddress.com.